# Python's json.load(sys.stdin) gets me u'...' instead of double quotes around Strings

Tags: python, json, parse-platform

When I do:

```
import sys, json;
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'X-Parse-Application-Id': '...',
       'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': '...'}

data = json.load(sys.stdin)
for station in data["data"]:
    print station
    res = requests.post('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/test4', data=station, headers=headers)
```

I get

```
{u'city': u'London',
...
}
```

And it's not a valid Json as when I try to POST it to Parse.com I'm getting

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid JSON"}
```

and any JSON validator gives me `Error:Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.`

How to make a valid JSON of the `data`?

Comment: it is not a json. it is a python's dict.

Comment: to convert python dict to JSON object, use json.dumps(station)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`print` will just print python's representation of the object you are passing (which you deserialized with `json.load`). Try this:

```
import sys, json;
data = json.load(sys.stdin)
for station in data["data"]:
    print(json.dumps(station))
```

`json.dumps` serializes a python object back to json.

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood what `json.load` does: it *deserializes* from JSON, ie it creates Python objects from JSON strings.

But I can't really understand what you're doing; if you already have JSON being passed in from stdin, why are you trying to convert it at all? Pass it straight on to your API.

Comment: I parse one REST API which gives me some array of Objects and then I try to put those array to my Parse.com account. AFAIK one cannot put array to Parse.com thus I'm looping thru that array and put Objects one by one.

Comment: Well then, as m fran suggests you should dump each element back to JSON.

Comment: Well then, shouldn't this be a comment as well? Since I think this *answer* didn't really solve the problem, right?